# Flutter: AnimatedContainer's animation based on child's width

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am trying to animate the container's width based on its children's width, using `AnimatedContainer`'s [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html) only tells to animate the width/height by hardcoded values.

```
AnimatedContainer(
          curve: Curves.linear,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimen.padding, vertical: Dimen.padding/2),
            child:Text(isPlaying ? Plurals.playingSounds(playingItems) : "Play",
                style: AppTypography.body()
            ),
          ),
      );
```

Output:

[image: Animated Container child based animation]

**Expected:** 
The animation should happen with `AnimatedContainer` on its width based on its children's width.

Comment: seems you need `AnimatedSize` - the docs say: *"Animated widget that automatically transitions its size over a given duration whenever the given child's size changes."*

Comment: @pskink I have tried `AnimatedSize` as well but it doesn't do the animation I am looking for. It doesn't animate the bound of the views to expand.

Comment: so try `SizeTransition`, something like: `child: AnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: 500.milliseconds,
  transitionBuilder: (w, a) => SizeTransition(sizeFactor: a, child: w, axis: Axis.horizontal,),
  child: Container(
    key: UniqueKey(),
    color: Colors.green,
    child: Text(elevation==2? 'short' : 'looooong looooong looooong', textScaleFactor: 2.0,),
  ),
)`

Comment: @pskink Tried `SizeTransition` now using your code as well as making changes to mine as well. Still no luck! Is your code working for you?

Comment: did you run my code? without *any* changes? if so, what do you see if you call `setState` and change `elevation` variable from 2 to 3 for example?

Comment: @pskink Yes, I did try your code and also update the value of  `elevation` on tap. But unfortunately, I am still getting the same result without the animation.

Comment: so what do you see? cant you see two labels? one is `short` and the second is `looooong looooong looooong` and they animate when changing `elevation` from 2 => 3 => 2 => 3 etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213539/discussion-between-vipul-asri-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink  I just ran your code in a new project and it works perfectly. I need to now look into my code what's the issue with it.

Comment: Though it works similar to `AnimatedSize` while in the container I have rounded corner's which are clipped while the animation is progress.

Comment: `class STTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _STTestState createState() => _STTestState();
}

class _STTestState extends State<STTest> {
var short = true;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var text = short? 'press me' : 'presssssss meeeeeeee';
return AnimatedSwitcher(
duration: 500.milliseconds,
transitionBuilder: (w, a) => SizeTransition(sizeFactor: a, child: w, axis: Axis.horizontal,),
child: RaisedButton(
key: UniqueKey(),
onPressed: () => setState(() => short = !short),
child: Text(text, textScaleFactor: 2.0,),
),
);
}
}`

Comment: @pskink I have tried this. I have tried your solution. Check this: https://easyupload.io/jbm7pz
Your solutions work but it clips the container border-radius while animating.

Comment: so use `ScaleTransition` instead